# How to parse an HTML string using CSS selectors?

Tags: google-apps-script, css-selectors, html-parsing

I am trying to extract some data from HTML page which is in string variable. I know that Google Apps Script code is executed server-side, and `document` object is not defined.

Is there any alternative easy way to extract data using CSS selectors like in `document.querySelector`?