# Google Apps Script: How to Save HTML Table exported as Excel File to Google Drive directly

Tags: excel, export

I want to save an HTML table as a Google Sheet using Google Apps script.

The following Javascript code allows me to download the file as an Excel file.

```js
function exportTableToExcel(table, name) {
  //alert('fired');
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
  , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
  , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
  , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  //return function(table, name) {
  if (!table.nodeType) {table = document.getElementById(table)}
  var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
  window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
```

What I want it to do, however, is save the file in Google Drive instead of downloading it.

How do I modify the code so the file gets saved to Google Drive instead of downloading?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `I want to save an HTML table as an Excel File to my Google Drive directly without downloading and uploading it using Google Apps script.` and your showing script and the HTML table. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Please see my edit above to clarify the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the HTML table as a text instead of an image? By the way, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I saw your updated question, you say `Basically, is there an easy way to take this HTML table with the formatting and save as Google Sheet on Google Drive?`. But, in your initial question, you said `I want to save an HTML table as an Excel File to my Google Drive directly without downloading and uploading it using Google Apps script.`. I cannot understand your expected result. Can I ask you about the details of your actual expected result?

Comment: Don't apologize for poor English skills. Your posts to other people have answered my questions so I appreciate your wisdom.
I modified question above with table HTML.
Basically, want to take table data with formatting and email it or download it as MS Excel file.
I already know how to email and download as Excel file. Just don't know how to import the table data into Google Sheet.
I am using a work-a-round for the formatting the time being. It involves using conditional formatting but it only works for the specific table, not any table with any formatting.

Comment: I modified my whole original post to make it shorter and to the point. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot find your HTML table in your updated question. I apologize for my poor English skill. But, about `Just don't know how to import the table data into Google Sheet.`, if you want to put the HTML table into Google Spreadsheet, this thread might be an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67010954